# php/ajax success and error message

Tags: php, html

I have been working on a database for a few weeks now and I just cannot get my php code to work.  I created a database to enter new borrower information into a library database.  I would like a Success! message to post if all the fields are filled in and an error message to show if any field is empty. After this, i would like to incorporate ajax so that the Success and Failure messages populate on the HTML page and do not open a second page.  Any help would be appreciated. My HTML and PHP codes are below.

HTML:

```
<body>
<form action="Addborrowerinfo.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Enter New Borrower Information</strong></legend>
        <legend>The form  below is used to send  data to  be stored in the database</legend>
        <p> Enter data in the  fields below and press Submit to add a new record to the database. To see the information you just entered, go back to the gather all data link below</p>

        <p>BorrowerID: <input type="text" name="BorrowerID" /></p>
        <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" /></p>
        <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" /></p>
        <p>Address: <input type="text" name="Address" /></p>
        <p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" /></p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
(connection info)

$BorrowerID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["BorrowerID"]);
$FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["FirstName"]);
$LastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["LastName"]);
$Address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Address"]);
$PhoneNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["PhoneNumber"]);

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO duf47_library.Borrowers (BorrowerID, FirstName, LastName, Address, PhoneNumber) VALUES ('$BorrowerID', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Address', '$PhoneNumber')");

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What happens with this code currently? Did your connection get established? What is `$insert`s result?

Comment: Periods shouldn't be used in table names.

Comment: When I enter info into the data fields that info is correctly being sent to the database.  A second page will open that is blank. $insert is working correctly and updating my database on another server. I want to try to get a success message to show on my original HTML page instead of it opening a second blank page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your (connection info) is. This biggest thing I see is that your `mysql_query("sql syntax")` should be `mysqli_query($db, "sql syntax")`. Your database is not being called and this is required in procedural php.

Here is the link with examples in the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php .